# Match values from different columns to rows only when several conditions met

Tags: r, for-loop, matching

The scenario is drag racing... sometimes drivers race against a competitor, sometimes they just race alone. The drivers and their skill level are always completely randomized. The race is over after 12 laps, and races occur once a day for 10 years. There are hundreds of drivers. Independent observers recorded data during the races, including the driver's speed, but only for one of the drivers! Therefore, data are missing. Here are the first 6 rows of the data:

```
    df <- data.frame(
      Driver_name =  c("Rick",  "Julie",  "Denver", "Johny",  "Cassandra", "Phillip"),
      Driver_level = c("A",     "C",      "D",      "A",      "B",         "B"),
      Driver_speed = c(96,       91,       89,       94,       88,          99),
      Competitor=    c("Yes",   "Yes",    "Yes",    "Yes",    "No",        "No"),
      Comp_name=     c("Julie", "Rick",   "Johnny", "Denver", "NA",        "NA"),
      Comp_level=    c("B",     "B",      "D",      "A",      "NA",        "NA"),
      Comp_speed=    c("???",   "???",    "???",    "???",    "NA",        "NA"),
      Race_day=      c(165,      165,      72,       72,       92,          65),
      Lap_number=    c(9,        9,        12,       12,       8,           4),
      Humidity=      c(33,       33,       88,       88,       12,          55),
      Temperature=   c(28,       28,       12,       12,       20,          28)
    )
```

Each row is for a different driver, but I need to fill in the data for the speed of the competitor! I'll manually enter the speeds to demonstrate what I need to do for the rest of the data set.

```
    df_1 <- data.frame(
      Driver_name =  c("Rick",  "Julie",  "Denver", "Johny",  "Cassandra", "Phillip"),
      Driver_level = c("A",     "C",      "D",      "A",      "B",         "B"),
      Driver_speed = c(96,       91,       89,       94,       88,          99),
      Competitor=    c("Yes",   "Yes",    "Yes",    "Yes",    "No",        "No"),
      Comp_name=     c("Julie", "Rick",   "Johnny", "Denver", "NA",        "NA"),
      Comp_level=    c("B",     "B",      "D",      "A",      "NA",        "NA"),
      Comp_speed=    c(91,       96,       94,       89,      "NA",        "NA"),
      Race_day=      c(165,      165,      72,       72,       92,          65),
      Lap_number=    c(9,        9,        12,       12,       8,           4),
      Humidity=      c(33,       33,       88,       88,       12,          55),
      Temperature=   c(28,       28,       12,       12,       20,          28)
    )
```

Comment: Are you considering `"NA"` to be missing values as well as `"???"`? Those NAs aren't properly set as `NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that a `left_join` is ideal for.

Your data

```
df <- data.frame(
  Driver_name =  c("Rick",  "Julie",  "Denver", "Johny",  "Cassandra", "Phillip"),
  Driver_level = c("A",     "C",      "D",      "A",      "B",         "B"),
  Driver_speed = c(96,       91,       89,       94,       88,          99),
  Competitor=    c("Yes",   "Yes",    "Yes",    "Yes",    "No",        "No"),
  Comp_name=     c("Julie", "Rick",   "Johnny", "Denver", "NA",        "NA"),
  Comp_level=    c("B",     "B",      "D",      "A",      "NA",        "NA"),
  Comp_speed=    c("???",   "???",    "???",    "???",    "NA",        "NA"),
  Race_day=      c(165,      165,      72,       72,       92,          65),
  Lap_number=    c(9,        9,        12,       12,       8,           4),
  Humidity=      c(33,       33,       88,       88,       12,          55),
  Temperature=   c(28,       28,       12,       12,       20,          28)
)
```

We load the `dplyr` package

```
#install.packages("dplyr") #if you don't have it
library(dplyr)
```

Let's get rid of the `Comp_speed` column that currently has "???" values.

```
df <- df %>% select(-Comp_speed)
```

Let's make a second dataframe with only the name and speed and we rename Driver_speed to Comp_speed on the fly.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  select(Driver_name, Comp_speed = Driver_speed)
```

Now we can `left_join` the `df` dataframe to `df2`. `Comp_name` in `df` is matched to `Driver_name` in `df2`

```
df_updated <- df %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("Comp_name" = "Driver_name"))
#> Warning: Column `Comp_name`/`Driver_name` joining factors with different
#> levels, coercing to character vector
```

This is the resulting dataframe `df_updated`

```
df_updated
#>   Driver_name Driver_level Driver_speed Competitor Comp_name Comp_level
#> 1        Rick            A           96        Yes     Julie          B
#> 2       Julie            C           91        Yes      Rick          B
#> 3      Denver            D           89        Yes    Johnny          D
#> 4       Johny            A           94        Yes    Denver          A
#> 5   Cassandra            B           88         No        NA         NA
#> 6     Phillip            B           99         No        NA         NA
#>   Race_day Lap_number Humidity Temperature Comp_speed
#> 1      165          9       33          28         91
#> 2      165          9       33          28         96
#> 3       72         12       88          12         NA
#> 4       72         12       88          12         89
#> 5       92          8       12          20         NA
#> 6       65          4       55          28         NA
```

#### Update:

As OP brings up, this is not robust to drivers racing each other more than once (an oversight on my part).

Assuming (from the data) the `Race_day` and `Lap_number` variables are enough to distinguish each head-to-head race, we'd simply keep them in our `df2` dataframe. And then join by those column names in our `left_join`. Here's what that would look like.

```r
df2 <- df %>% 
  select(Driver_name, Comp_speed = Driver_speed, Race_day, Lap_number)

df_updated <- df %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("Comp_name" = "Driver_name", "Race_day", "Lap_number"))
#> Warning: Column `Comp_name`/`Driver_name` joining factors with different
#> levels, coercing to character vector
```

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for answering so quickly! `left_join` was a great idea! Although, does it matter that a) during every race, drivers' names are listed 12 times (for each lap), b) the same drivers race again and again, with different pairings, c) sometimes drivers don't race with pairs? It would appear to me that `df` needs to be joined by terms other than just `Driver_name`.

Comment: Yes, sorry that I didn't catch that. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the solution!

Answer (score 1):

We need to left join df to itself.
!names(df)%in%c("Comp_speed") removes the variable Comp_speed from the first dataframe x.

df[,c("Driver_name","Driver_speed")] only includes variables Driver_name and Driver_speed in the second dataframe y.

In summary, the Comp_name from x gets matched to the Driver_name from y and the Driver_speed from y is reported as Driver_speed.y (Driver_speed.y because Driver_speed already exists in the df, which after the join changes name to Driver_speed.x):

```
df <- merge(x=df[,!names(df)%in%c("Comp_speed")],y=df[,c("Driver_name","Driver_speed")],by.x="Comp_name",by.y="Driver_name",all.x=TRUE)
```

Now, we just need to change the names of "Driver_speed.x","Driver_speed.y" to "Driver_speed","Comp_speed":

```
library("data.table")
setnames(df,c("Driver_speed.x","Driver_speed.y"),c("Driver_speed","Comp_speed"))
```

Comment: @camille I added the explanation and also found a typo in my code! thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess `df$Comp_speed <- df$Driver_speed[with(df,match(Comp_name,Driver_name))]` could work for your purpose